# How to get the VBA code auto select fields from Content Control drop down options

Tags: vba, vba7, word-automation, word-contentcontrol

I wish to auto populate value from content control drop down option. I have four options in the drop down list and I want option 1 to be populated for Case Methodology.

While trying the below code is giving me:

> VBA 6124 error- You can not edit it because it is protected,

Code:

```vb
Select Case oCC.Title
            Case "Methodology"
                oCC.Range.Text = " abc"
            Case "Methodology2"
                oCC.Range.Text = "NA"
```

I tried .LockContents=False but it is not working either. How can I write the code that can autoselect first value from the four options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a dropdown content control, `Range.Text` is read-only.

You have to use:

```vb
oCC.DropdownListEntries(2).Select
```

`2` because usually the placeholder text is the first in your list.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much:) One last question, I'm using this code, do you know how can I add border in the table while pasting it in word. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Participants - C").Range("C7:D13").Copy
docWord.Bookmarks("TransParties").Range.Paste.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your response. SO is not allowing me to post any other question in 90 min, it would need to get done with it. I would appreciate if you can share the resolution.